# I can't boot Ubuntu anymore

Tags: boot, shutdown

I have been using Ubuntu as my sole operating system on my Dell computer since 3 years. The battery pack of my computer is not working anymore, and in the past month my computer has been taken off the electric grid without closing down properly quite a number of times (I was staying with elderly family members who on multiple occasions just unplugged the device when they needed the plug). Recently I started getting notices of 'system program problem detected'. I reported these quite some times but my system was still working fine. Then I started having a problem with programs freezing while working in them, and the only solution was to once again just shut the computer down unproperly. A couple of days ago, I wanted to delete my Skype version in order to download a newer version, but while removing Skype, my computer froze again and I had to shutdown. Since then, I get the screen in the picture [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfYvU.jpg) when trying to boot. I have only very limited knowledge about computers and commands etc. so I have no idea what to do. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem please?

```
[    0,044628] ACPI Error: [_SB_,PCI.RPO 5.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload2-191)
[    0.044637] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, lookup/catalog (20170831/psob.ject-253)
[    0.044639] ACPI Error: Ignore error and continue tablead (20170831/psobject-642)
[    0.044641] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode Scope (20170831/psloop-559)
[    0.044988] ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI.RP 09.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload2-191)
[    0.044992] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170831/psobject-253)
[    0.044994] ACPI Error: Ignore error and continue table load (20170831/psobject-642)
[    0.044996] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode Scope (20170833/psloop-559)
[    1.298496] psmouse serio1: elantech: elantech_send_cmd query 0x02 failed.
[    1.298520] psmouse serio1: elantech: failed to query capabilities.
/dev/sda3 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda3: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY 
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda3 requires a manual fsck


BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.3) built-in shell (ash) Enter "help' for a list of built-in commands. (initramfs)
```

Comment: If you care about the data on the disk and you have no expertise, please *do not* run `fsck -y` blindly. The hardware might be faulting and you would risk making things worse. Try following a guide to take an image of the disk with `ddrescue`, or have an expert do it for you. Save the image on another disk. This way, you have the best odds of saving your data while the disk is not completely broken yet.

Comment: The issues you describe indicate that a hardware fault is not improbable at all. A failing disk can result in system instability and freezes.

Comment: Have you tried entering the BIOS, asking it to use default values, save and reboot?

Comment: You may want to consider if taking regular backups of your data is worth your time.  If you have that you can always reinstall Ubuntu if broken or move to another system without losing data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to the sudden shutdowns the filesystem got corrupted. This might not be a problem as modern filesystems are quite resilient.
Try running the fsck as suggested at the busybox prompt `fsck -y /dev/sda3`.

Comment: @Bea if the answer was useful, don't forged to mark it as accepted

Comment: [fsck can be dangerous](https://serverfault.com/questions/786648/when-is-fsck-dangerous) if the problem is in the hardware. Shutdowns alone are unlikely to be the only problem, since OP indicates system instability and freezes. Please always suggest taking an image of the disk with `ddrescue` or similar tools before attempting `fsck -y`.